# RSpec feature test for inherited Devise Registrations Controller - "Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cant assign requested address"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, capybara

I have a Rails 4.2 app using Devise. I had to customize the `Registrations` controller in `#create`, and whenever I run my feature specs, I keep getting the error:

```
Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cant assign requested address - connect(2) for nil port 0
```

[image]

I'm out of ideas. What's going on? All my devise controller specs work fine, testing manually works fine, but what configuration remains?

My feature spec:
/spec/features/visitor/visitor_can_signup_spec.rb

[image]

Comment: did you have a look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/644 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13853962/1033737 ?

Comment: what is the :devise metadata tag on your feature doing? Is it used to start an auth server of some kind for those feature tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had my `config/environments/test.rb` had the wrong mailer setting.

I had

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

so i changed it to:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```