# Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL when sending a request to api from Rails on Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, google-api

### What I want to do

I want to get the response of book information by hitting google books api from Book model of Rails

### The error that occurred

```
web_1 | Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL (Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Address not available-connect(2) for nil port 80)):
web_1 |
web_1 | app/models/book.rb:24:in `search'
web_1 | app/controllers/books_controller.rb:3:in `search'
```

### code

Hit the API using the keywords (book name, author, etc.) sent from the form.

```
class BooksController <ApplicationController
  def search
    @results = Book.search(params[:book_search][:search_key_word])
  end
end
```

Since it contains non-ASCII characters, it is encoded using the `url_encode` method.

```
class Book <ApplicationRecord
  class << self
    def search(key_word)
      api_endpoint = ERB::Util.url_encode("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{key_word}&maxResults=20")
      response = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(api_endpoint)) # I'm getting the above error.
      JSON.parse(response)
    end
  end
end
```

Executing the curl command for the same endpoint will of course give the proper response.

Is there something to do with using docker?
It is based on alpine linux.
https://hub.docker.com/layers/ruby/library/ruby/2.6.6-alpine/images/sha256-95d5b6bf7084a6a0f04b48a7fc1c533ccb15e1550c670ff589ef56e620f40286?context=explore

### Environment

- docker 2.3.0.4
- docker-compose 3.8
- rails container base image ruby:2.6.6-alpine
- ruby 2.6.6
- rails 6.0.3.2

---

I would be grateful if you could teach me if you have any idea.
Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Just sounds to me like maybe Rails is not listening/binding to the correct interface ? What IP is it listening/binding to ? Maybe it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853936/cannot-assign-requested-address-bind2-errnoeaddrnotavail ?

Comment: Thank you for the information and thanks!
However, there was no problem in that regard.

docker-compose command
`rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'`

I solved it, so I will list the cause.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

solved.

The cause is

```
ERB::Util.url_encode("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{key_word}&maxResults=20")
```

When the character string returned when encoded in this part was passed to URI.parse as it was, URI::Generic was returned. It seems that uri host and scheme are both nil and could not be acquired correctly.
Since it is passed to Net::HTTP.get as it is, the error like the title occurred.

`URI.encode` is deprecated, so I wanted to encode it with another method.
Finally, when URI.parse was performed on the character string encoded using `WEBrick::HTTPUtils.#escape`, an instance of URI::HTTP was returned, and the scheme etc. were set correctly and it was solved.

Thank you very much.

reference

```
def search(key_word)
  uri = URI.parse(WEBrick::HTTPUtils.escape("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{key_word}&maxResults=20"))
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```